# Is there a minimum height for the electrical disconnect to a small sub-panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, code-compliance

We built a new detached garage. As sub-panel was installed inside the garage at about 45" height. Now that its installation is completed, the inspector said the subpanel needs an electrical disconnect. I would like to install the electrical disconnect box right below the subpanel to avoid running new cable from the main all the way to the new electrical disconnect box. Having said that, it means the new electrical disconnect box would be install between 28" to 36" height. If I have to place the electrical disconnect box at the same height as the subpanel, there is not enough cable, and that is the reason that I would need to run new cable.
So, what is the minimum height for an electrical disconnect box?
Thank you.

Comment: STOP CONSTRUCTION. You do not need a *literal, physical disconnect box*.  Minor modifications to your existing panel will suffice.  We need to see a photo of your subpanel and need to know if it is "convertible" to main breaker.  I'm after that, and how many breakers are in it, and what type.  We can probably do this with $20 in parts and zero construction.

Answer (score 3):

There's a maximum height, **NEC 404.8(a) - center of the grip of the operating handle not more than 2.0 meters (6'7") above floor level**, but there is no minimum height defined in NEC. Possible but unlikely to have a local modification to adopted code, but plain vanilla NEC does not define one.

Of course, you can simply use a junction box rather than running a whole new cable if you want it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

> We built a new detached garage. As sub-panel was installed inside the garage at about 45" height. Now that its installation is completed, the inspector said the subpanel needs an electrical disconnect.

STOP CONSTRUCTION! The inspector doesn't mean a *literal, physical* disconnect *box*.

The inspector means that your installation must **serve as** a disconnect; however it gets to to exploit the "Rule of Six" which says the disconnect can be made up of up to six actual switches (e.g. your breakers).

As a practical matter, you never add a literal, actual disconnect switch to an installation like this.  You either

- rely on having <=6 breakers; those ARE your disconnects.
- use Handle Ties to tie 2-3 breakers at a time, so you get under 6 hand movements.
- retrofit a main breaker, if the panel is "convertible"
- Install a "back-feed" main breaker in a normal breaker position, using a tie down kit.

So get us a photo or description of your panel and we'll find the easiest cheapest way.  No need for construction.

### The Code says

> **225.30 Number of Supplies.** A building or other structure that is served by a branch circuit or feeder on the load side of a service disconnecting means shall be supplied by only one feeder or branch circuit unless (deleted since none apply to you)
>
> **225.31 Disconnecting Means.** Means shall be provided for disconnecting all ungrounded conductors that supply or pass through the building or structure.
>
> **225.32 Location.** The disconnecting means shall be installed either inside or outside of the building or structure served or where the conductors pass through the building or structure. The disconnecting means shall be at a readily accessible location nearest the point of entrance of the conductors. For the purposes of this section, the requirements in 230.6 shall be utilized.
>
> **225.33 Maximum Number of Disconnects.**
> **(A) General.** The disconnecting means for each supply permitted by 225.30 shall consist of not more than six switches or six circuit breakers mounted in a single enclosure, in a group of separate enclosures, or in or on a switchboard or switchgear. There shall be no more than six disconnects per supply grouped in any one location.

That last one is the "Rule of Six" we're referring to.

Answer (score -1):

If the subpanel is run from a breaker in the main panel, it has a disconnect. There are minimum height requirements for garages, because the garage is typically where you would store flammable fluids, and those vapors are typically heavier than air.  You would want to make sure you aren't violating that code as well.

Comment: A *detached* garage panel with more than 6 breakers requires a **local** disconnect.

Comment: @Ecnerwal you mean breaker HAND MOVEMENTS... often reducible by our friend  Mr. Handle Tie!